# How to make Parametric Shapes in Unity3D that can be baked in relistic quality

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, rendering

I am using Unity C# Script to create shapes.
My shapes can be like box (6 faces without rounded corner), curve and polygon.
I create shapes with basic method like creating new Mesh and Meshfilter. Then assigning UVs, Normals, Vertices etc to the mesh. Usually one cube shape contains 24 vertices. But these shapes are not giving me realistic results when I Bake my scene.
Right now my output after baking scene is like
[image]

My box details are

[image]

Here is my code sample

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        GameObject Shape = new GameObject("Cupboard");
        MeshRenderer mr = Shape.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mr.material = Material;
        MeshFilter meshFilter = Shape.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        meshFilter.mesh.Clear();

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = Vertices(); 
        //It return vertices of each face (total 24)
        // 1 face= 4 corners
        // 1 corner = 3 points(x,y,z)
        // 1 box have total 8 corners. So 8x3=24
        mesh.triangles = Triangles();
        // this function will return traingles (total 12 traingles)
        // 1 face = 2 triangles
        // 1 box have total 6 faces. So 6x2=12
        mesh.uv = UV(); // returns UVs for each face

        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
```

I want this kind of output. [Youtube Link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYBEndFphik&ab_channel=UnityUnity)
If I use some pre-made FBX models, that models are giving better result than the models I created myself from Unity3D Scripting. Can someone guide me how to make it possible?
Please ignore ***I can't bake at run-time*** or ***it might take long time***.
My target is to display [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYBEndFphik&ab_channel=UnityUnity) kind of output. How do I make shapes by using scripting that can give me this kind of output?

If this method is not suitable, then where can I draw a box that can be used to get realistic output after baking in Unity3d? I just want unity3d to bake.

Comment: Use better models then? It's a bit unclear what you are asking exactly ... You can't expect a cube you made up from 24 verts to have the same amount of details as models in the video you linked ....

Comment: I am going to update questoin, you can read again

Comment: Is this a question about the lighting, or about the geometry?

Comment: @LeoBartkus yes

Comment: generating that geometry is a big project.  Take a look at the geometry nodes feature in blender for inspiration.

Comment: the lighting, on the other hand, is not baked in your target example video.  That video uses screen space realtime reflection.

Comment: @LeoBartkus I don't think so, they are using realtime effects as well but that much realistic environments looks like has been baked

Comment: https://blog.unity.com/technology/bedroom-demo-archviz-with-ssrr